# Passing HTML into labels

Tags: chartist.js

Is it possible to pass an HTML node into labels? I specifically was looking to make the label also a hyperlink - e.g. `<a href="bla">Label</a>`. I also saw someone asked about [Chartist label as image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337839/chartist-label-as-image), which this would also resolve.

I tired populating the labels array w/ HTML and with dom nodes (`createElement`). I also tried passing dom nodes and string containing HTML through `labelInterpolationFnc` without luck.

Is there any way to accomplish this?